# React app, after getting data from initial get request, onChange doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, dom, input, redux, server

```
 constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      AyarAdi: '',
      Bilgi: '',
      FirmaKodu: '',
      icerik: {
        smsUser: '',
        smsApi: '',
        mesajAciklama: '',
        password: ''
      },
      errors: {}
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.AyarlarListesiAl(this.props.user.userCreds.FirmaKodu)
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      icerik: {
        ...this.state.icerik,
        [event.target.name]: [event.target.value]
      }
    })
  }


 render(){
        <div>
          <InputGroup className='mb-3'>
            <FormControl
              name='password'
              placeholder='SMS Şifre'
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={
                this.props.data.AyarlarListesi[0] !== undefined
                  ? JSON.parse(this.props.data.AyarlarListesi[0].Bilgi).password
                  : this.state.icerik.password
              }
              style={{ maxWidth: 400, height: 40 }}
            />
            <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {this.state.errors['password']}
            </span>
          </InputGroup>
        </div>
        }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
  data: state.data
})

....
```

The problem is, in componentDidMount, I send a get request to the server via Redux action,  and it gets me data from the redux reducer state; `AyarlarListesi`. I wanted to fetch the data to the input elements value, So when a user opens the page, he/she can update the previous data just changing it on the input and clicks to submit. I can successfully put the data to the input but I can't change the value of the input, it stays stable, the handleChange function doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: If your `AyarlarListesi ` array have element on 0th index, then value is set from props data and not `state` data, and in `onChange` handler, you are changing state data. So your changes will not get reflected.

Comment: How can I pass the data to the components state? in componentDidmount, it didn't do immediately, in render, I can pass it to a variable but can not to the state by setState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handleChange function only manipulates the state. However the value to be displayed comes preferrably from props and only if the props field is not available it will fall back to the state variable.

To display the state variable after changing it via user input, you could either swap the condition and make it so the state variable will be displayed unless it's empty (and use the props variable as a fallback) or you could instead update the state variable initially when you get new props.

Assuming you never change props from outside or don't care about later updates, this would be my preferred way of solving your problem:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.props.AyarlarListesiAl(this.props.user.userCreds.FirmaKodu);
  if (this.props.data.AyarlarListesi[0] !== undefined) {
    this.setState({
      icerik: {
        ...this.state.icerik,
        password: JSON.parse(this.props.data.AyarlarListesi[0].Bilgi).password,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Also in your FormControl skip checking if the props data is set and instead always use `this.state.icerik.password` as the value.

If your props from outside could change and you'd like to restart whenever a new password or `AyarlarListesi` is passed from outside, you should update the state in componentDidUpdate again:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.data.AyarlarListesi !== props.data.AyarlarListesi && props.data.AyarlarListesi[0] !== undefined) {
    this.setState({
      icerik: {
        ...this.state.icerik,
        password: JSON.parse(this.props.data.AyarlarListesi[0].Bilgi).password,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work, because, in the beginning, the props is undefined, so it never gets in the condition and fills the state

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to update state on prop changes.
Note: This doesn't check if you might've changed the state already, so if your prop changes from the outside it will override any changes you made to the state variable in the meantime